# Regular expression for 4 or 5 digits in a row followed by a letter in a longer string?

Tags: regex, notepad++

For a text like

```
1" 77568T86 34 
2" 5347A1Q 456
```

I'd like to return strings `77568T`and `5437A`

I'm guessing I want something that begins like `\d{4,5}`

EDIT: Thanks for all the responses. Unfortunately, nothing is working in notepad++, even though they work with online regex testers.

I think the problem is notepad++'s handling of {} because `(\d[A-Z])` finds matches.

Advice?

Comment: What version of NP++ are you using? Here with V6.1.2 `\b\d{4,5}[A-Z]` works perfectly.

Comment: I was running an old version. I've got 6.1.5 and everything works now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you're on the right track. Just add a single `[A-Z]` following the number group (use `[A-Za-z]` if it should be case insensitive).

```
\d{4,5}[A-Z]
```

If it should be preceded by whitespace or some boundary, prepend a `\b`

```
\b\d{4,5}[A-Z]
```

I'm not familiar with how Notepad++ handles match capture groups, but it is likely you will want the whole thing surrounded in `()`

```
\b(\d{4,5}[A-Z])
```

Answer (score 1):

You got the number bit right; you just need to add a letter class to the end of your expression:

```
\d{4,5}[a-zA-Z]
```

(this allows upper or lower case; remove the `a-z` if you only want upper case)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
\d{4,5}[A-Z]
```

[See for yourself](http://regexr.com?31qtg)

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `(?i)\b\d{4,5}[a-z]`